# html/css3 - curved line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help to create a curved line with edges fading in css3/html5 like the image [image: curved line]

I have been looking at this example [from codepen](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/PwWjLL) but the edges are not fading

```
.box{
  width:500px; height:100px;  
  border:solid 5px #000;
  border-color:#000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100px 100px 0 0;
}
 <div class="box"></div>
```

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy paste this on your `HTML`

```css
.box{
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #F98821;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px / 91px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px / 91px;
 border-radius: 200px / 91px; 
}

.box:before {
 content: '';
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #fff;
 -moz-border-radius: 193px / 70px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 193px / 70px;
 border-radius: 193px / 70px;
 top:13px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using viewport units are best for responsiveness

```css
.holi {
  border-top: orange solid 5px;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 14vh;
  border-radius: 25vw / 7vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="holi">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Reference](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

```css
.box{
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background: orange;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px / 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px / 100px;
 border-radius: 200px / 100px; 
}

.box:after {
 content: '';
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #fff;
 -moz-border-radius: 200px / 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 200px / 100px;
 border-radius: 200px / 100px;

 top:13px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```